# which version of sonarqube gradle plugin compatible with jdk 7?

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, java-7

I am trying to integrate sonarqube gradle plugin with jdk7 but build is failing due to version mismatch.
Gralde version 4.3
JDK  1.7
Sonarqube-gradle plugin ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.0.1 was the last version to support Java 7

- https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-gradle/releases/tag/2.0.1
- https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-gradle/blob/2.0.1/build.gradle#L24..L25